# Include static lib in shared object?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, unix-ar, object-files

I would like to compile a bunch of static libs into a shared object. So far I have

```
g++ -Wl -shared -fPIC -o myshared.so objs/*.o
```

Where the objs/*.o above contains all the object files extracted from the various static libs using ar.

UPDATE: basically, I'm wondering if I might be able to use the .a files directly on the command line without having to extract them.

Comment: I would really avoid mixing non PIC code (which is the usual flavor inside static libraries) with PIC code (PIC = Position Independent Code). You'll get a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is a 2 step process:

```
ar -x mylib.a
gcc -shared *.o -o mylib.so
```

Comment: OK, I was hoping g++ could do it all at once.

Comment: Actually you can: `-Wl,--whole-archive,foo.a,--no-whole-archive` (not sure I got the option name quite right). I second what @Basil said about NON-PIC code though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot use `gcc -shared -o foo.so foo.a` is because archives are treatment differently in that object files from the archive are only used to resolve undefined symbols — of which there are none, since you specified no prior .o files.